# Display neo4j node properties with Sigma.js

Tags: javascript, neo4j, sigma.js

I am using Sigma.js with the cypher plugin to visualise my neo4j database. After following the simple example here https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/load-neo4j-cypher-query.html , it is working well. I edited the plugin so that the graph labels displayed are the names of my neo4j nodes, however I would also like to show the other node properties when clicking on the label or node.I am quite new to JavaScript so would like to know if this is possible for a beginner like me to do and if it is where is the best place for me to start.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register an event on the click or hover node.
There is an example into sigmajs for event : https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/events.html

This is a short code that demonstrate how to make this. Replace the alert method by what you want.

```
sigma.bind('overNode', function(event) {
  alert(event.data.node);
});
```

If you just want to discover your database,  take a look at tank-browser : https://www.npmjs.com/package/tank-browser

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit [Cypher](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.neo4j.cypher) plugin

First: Define var let's assume we will call it "has" at the beginning of the file.

Second: You should add ul in your html and add class to it called 'popover'

Third: Add to cypherCallback  method you should add inside else if (typeof sig === 'object')

```
                sig.graph.read(graph);
                sig.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
                var clicknode = e.data.node;
            // empty the printed list                    
               $('.popover').empty();  
                has='';    
            // create the tlis tof prop. from returend Object
            for(var keys in clicknode.neo4j_data ){
               $('.popover').append(' <li>' + keys + ' = '+  clicknode.neo4j_data[keys] + '</li>'); 
has+= 'n.' +keys + '="'+ clicknode.neo4j_data[keys] + '"AND ';
}                   
            $('.popover').show();
});                  
          sig.bind('clickStage', function(e) {
             $('.popover').hide();
           });
```